# Access pod from external public url

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I created this test helm chart which I want to access via public url domain:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/external_domain_helm_chart_poc/blob/main/pod-chart/templates/ingressresource.yaml

Ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: registry-domain-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: monitor.somedomain.org
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ include "pod.fullname" . }}
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I added a record into public DNS register:

```
monitor.somedomain.org ->  4.4.4.4 (node1)
monitor.somedomain.org ->  4.4.4.5 (node2)
```

But when I try to open the url link page is not loaded. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Since you are using a public domain name and pointing it to your nodes IP addresses (4.4.4.4 and 4.4.4.5), your present ingress configuration does not explicitly specify a nodeport. As a result, you must configure the ingress controller to utilize a nodeport.

Comment: Can you show me how I need to edit the hem chart, please?

Comment: What ingress controller are you using ?

Comment: @ALex_hha please see the repository into the post.

Comment: I don't see any controllers. You can't use ingress without controller

Comment: Can you show me how I can add it into my code, please?

Comment: Actually ingress controller is not related to a chart. So probably it's a bad idea include it. You can read more at https://blog.palark.com/comparing-ingress-controllers-for-kubernetes/

Comment: I want to have everything configured using config files

Answer (score 0):

**There are probably a few different reasons why you are having trouble using the public URL to access your Helm chart application.**

Since you are using a public domain name and pointing it to your nodes IP addresses (4.4.4.4 and 4.4.4.5), your present ingress configuration does not explicitly specify a nodeport. As a result, you must configure the ingress controller to utilize a nodeport. This enables internet-based external traffic to reach the pods.

You may achieve this by adding a port to your Service yaml file under ports with the name nodePort, from the [service-node-port-range](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) (which is by default 30000-32767). The nodePort will then be known to you beforehand. To ensure that the nodePort is used in the Service yaml, ConfigMap, and Deployment, you can use Helm to pass in the nodePort as a parameter.

**Here's how to use a nodeport by modifying your ingress yaml:**

```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: registry-domain-ingress #descriptive name for your ingress resource
    spec:
      rules:# List of routing rules for your ingress
        - host: monitor.somedomain.org #your public domain name
          http:# specifies HTTP routing configuration 
            paths:
              - path: / #Matches any path (root path)
                pathType: Prefix #Match requests that start with this path
                backend:# Defines the backend service to route traffic 
                  service:
                    name: {{ include "pod.fullname" . }}#replace with the actual pod service name
                    port:
                      number: 80 #port number of the service (usually 80 for HTTP)
    
       ingress classname:<ingress -class-name>If you want to using a specific ingress class
     external Traffic policy:Local #If required for your configuration 
      Ports: #List of ports exposed by the ingress
     -name :http #optional name for the port 
      Port:80 # External port exposed to the internet
      target port:80 #pod port (port where your application listens)
      nodeport:300080 # choose an unused Nodeport (eg:30080)
```

**By following below  these steps and carefully reviewing your ingress,DNS,firewalls and application health you should be able to successfully access your helm chart application through the public URL**

Make sure your K8s cluster has an ingress controller installed.

Examine your ingress controller's logs to check if there are any mistakes or problems with how the ingress resource is processed.

Confirm  that the firewall rules linked to your nodes permit incoming traffic on the selected Nodeport (in this case, port 30080).

Use **kubectl get pods** to verify that the pods in your application service are operational and healthy.

Double check that service name in your ingress backend definition matches the name of the service deployed in your helm chart and namespace

Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6821) for more information

Comment: Sorry, can you format properly the code example, please?

Comment: Currently I can open a page using `4.4.4.4:30098` and see pod's web page. But domain is not working.

Comment: Since you can access the page using the node IP and Nodeport (http://4.4.4.4:30098) It means that your application itself is running sucessfully.but not through the public domain (monitor.somedomain.org) indicaes an issue with how the ingresss routes traffic bases on the domain name

Comment: Double check that your web browser sucessfully resolves the  **monitor . somedomain . org** to the correct IP addresses of your nodes. you can also use a tool like a  **host monitor . somedomain.org**  on your machine to verify

Comment: Make sure the DNS resolution is successfully mapping **monitor.somedomain.org**  to the IP addresses of your nodes (4.4.4.4 and 4.4.4.5) and that your cluster is able to communicate with the public DNS server.

Comment: Wait patiently for updates to DNS records. To confirm that the updated record containing your node's IP address has been made, use the dig or nslookup commands. Give the modifications you make to your public DNS record (monitor.somedomain.org) up to 24 hours to take effect globally.

Comment: @ Peter Penzov Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes,I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue f yes, please upvote and accept the answer. If not, I am happy to assist further

Comment: I tried to implement it but I get this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1156985/configure-ingress-controller-on-native-kubernetes

Comment: Can you update the above configuration, please? Indentation is not very clear.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting Now?

Comment: when I type the domain into my browser page `monitor.somedomain.org` it's not loaded. But when I do `monitor.somedomain.org:30098` I can see the page

Comment: The fact that you can access the pod using the domain name with the Nodeport (monitor.somedomain.org:3098) but not without it (monitor.somedomain.org)strongly suggests an issue with the ingress configuration or DNS propagation

Comment: looks like DNS is working but configuration is not. Let me propose you this. Can you open a PR into the Github Project so that I can see what exact changes I need to make?

Comment: Ensure the ingressresource.yaml file points the host field to your exact domain name (monitor.somedomain.org) No typos or extra spaces

Comment: verify the **backend** section correctly references the service backing your pod

Comment: use **kubectl get service** to confirm the service name

Comment: Make sure the Ingress resource targets port 80 (the port your pod listens on)

Comment: Sometimes restarting the Ingress controller can help resolve configuration issues

Comment: If your Ingress configuration is complex try creating a simpler one with just a single host rule pointing to your service.This can help isolate any configuration errors

Comment: @ Peter Penzov Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes,I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue f yes, please upvote and accept the answer. If not, I am happy to assist further –

Comment: No, still not working....

Comment: Now what is the error you are getting

Comment: Page is just not loaded.